# Is it possible to change the task colors in the timeline?

Tags: task-list, timeline

I want to change the colors of tasks in a timeline that I have. Can this be done? How?

Thanks you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To manually change event/callout colors in a timeline or project summary:

1. Go to your task list
2. Select the Task in the timeline (opens the Timeline menu)
3. Click the paint bucket and/or the font color icons to specify the colors of a specific event in the timeline.

The font color obviously will change the color of the text identifying a task. For tasks with a start and end date that show as a bar, the paint bucket changes the fill color of the task. For callouts (events with only a start OR due date) the paint bucket changes the color of the line connecting the callout text to the timeline.

Note that if you have a project summary associated with the task list, changing the colors of the task list will also affect the project summary (and vice versa).

Answer (score 0):

For the people who is looking for change the timeline color based on status, use the following code.

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("updateColors");

    setTimeout(
        function updateColors() {
            debugger;
            $(".ms-tl-mainArea .ms-tl-barTitle").each(function () {
                var taskStatus = getTaskStatus($(this).text());
                if (taskStatus == "Raised") {
                    $(this).parent().css("background-color", "#FFBF00");
                }
                if (taskStatus == "In Progress") {
                    $(this).parent().css("background-color", "green");
                }
                if (taskStatus == "Completed") {
                    $(this).parent().css("background-color", "blue");
                }
            });
        }, 5000);

    function getTaskStatus(taskname) {
        debugger;
        var status = "";
        var nameIndex = 0;
        var statusIndex = 0;

        //get Task Name column index and Task Status column index
        $(".ms-listviewtable tr th").each(function (i) {
            if ($(this).find("a").text() == "InitiativeName") {
                nameIndex = i;
            }
            if ($(this).find("a").text() == "Status") {
                statusIndex = i;
            }
        });

        $(".ms-listviewtable tr").each(function (i) {
            if (i > 0) {
                var name = $(this).children("td").eq(nameIndex).text();
                if (name == taskname) {
                    status = $(this).children("td").eq(statusIndex).text();
                }
            }
        });
        return status;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the column index for task name and task status, it´s needed to change the find("a") or "InitiativeName" parameters?

Same case for children("td") and eq(nameIndex)/eq(statusIndex).

Thanks a lot for you help.